# Add a back button to payment.html in module

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to add a back button to payment.html in my module.

I added the button in the html in my module like this:

```
<!--
 <li id="payment" role="presentation" class="checkout-payment-method" data-bind="fadeVisible: isVisible">
<div id="checkout-step-payment"
     class="step-content"
     data-role="content"
     role="tabpanel"
     aria-hidden="false">
    <!-- ko if: (quoteIsVirtual) -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('customer-email') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!--/ko-->
    <!--/ko-->
    <form id="co-payment-form" class="form payments" novalidate="novalidate">
        <input data-bind='attr: {value: getFormKey()}' type="hidden" name="form_key"/>
        <fieldset class="fieldset">
            <legend class="legend">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Payment Information'"></span>
            </legend><br />
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('beforeMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
            <div id="checkout-payment-method-load" class="opc-payment" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable">
                <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('payment-methods-list') -->
                    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <button class="button action continue primary" data-bind="goToPrevStep()">
                <span data-bind="i18n: 'Back'"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="no-quotes-block" data-bind="visible: isPaymentMethodsAvailable() == false">
                <!-- ko i18n: 'No Payment method available.'--><!-- /ko -->
            </div>
            <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('afterMethods') -->
                <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

But i'm unsure on the best way to add the js. I tried overwriting the payment.js but ofcourse then i also need to copy over the all the dependancies.

Is there any better way to do this.

I know I need something like this

```
        goToPrevStep:function(){
        stepNavigator.next();
    },
```

That is dependent on stepNavigator. But i'm unsure where to exactly put it.

Or is [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/95949/how-can-i-implement-the-back-button-in-magento) the best solution? I feel like there should be a prettier solution, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UPDATE: Since I first asked this question I found a better way to do it:

NEW ANSWER:

1. I extended the LayoutProcessor by making a plugin. Then I added the following code to add the new back button:

   ```
   public function aroundProcess(
       \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
       \Closure $proceed,
       array $jsLayout
   )
   {
       $jsLayoutResult = $proceed($jsLayout);

       if ($this->getQuote()->isVirtual()) {
           return $jsLayoutResult;
       }

      $jsLayoutResult['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['afterMethods']['children']['back-button']['component'] = 'BB_Checkout/js/view/back-button';

      return $jsLayoutResult;
   ```

   }
2. I have overwritten the step-navigator.js to add a back function:

> step-navigator-overwrite.js

```
define([
'jquery',
'ko'
], function ($, ko) {
'use strict';

var steps = ko.observableArray();

return {
    steps: steps,
    stepCodes: [],
    validCodes: [],

    /**
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    handleHash: function () {
        var hashString = window.location.hash.replace('#', ''),
            isRequestedStepVisible;

        if (hashString === '') {
            return false;
        }

        if ($.inArray(hashString, this.validCodes) === -1) {
            window.location.href = window.checkoutConfig.pageNotFoundUrl;

            return false;
        }

        isRequestedStepVisible = steps.sort(this.sortItems).some(function (element) {
            return (element.code == hashString || element.alias == hashString) && element.isVisible(); //eslint-disable-line
        });

        //if requested step is visible, then we don't need to load step data from server
        if (isRequestedStepVisible) {
            return false;
        }

        steps.sort(this.sortItems).forEach(function (element) {
            if (element.code == hashString || element.alias == hashString) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                element.navigate(element);
            } else {
                element.isVisible(false);
            }

        });

        return false;
    },

    /**
     * @param {String} code
     * @param {*} alias
     * @param {*} title
     * @param {Function} isVisible
     * @param {*} navigate
     * @param {*} sortOrder
     */
    registerStep: function (code, alias, title, isVisible, navigate, sortOrder) {
        var hash;

        if ($.inArray(code, this.validCodes) !== -1) {
            throw new DOMException('Step code [' + code + '] already registered in step navigator');
        }

        if (alias != null) {
            if ($.inArray(alias, this.validCodes) !== -1) {
                throw new DOMException('Step code [' + alias + '] already registered in step navigator');
            }
            this.validCodes.push(alias);
        }
        this.validCodes.push(code);
        steps.push({
            code: code,
            alias: alias != null ? alias : code,
            title: title,
            isVisible: isVisible,
            navigate: navigate,
            sortOrder: sortOrder
        });
        this.stepCodes.push(code);
        hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

        if (hash != '' && hash != code) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
            //Force hiding of not active step
            isVisible(false);
        }
    },

    /**
     * @param {Object} itemOne
     * @param {Object} itemTwo
     * @return {Number}
     */
    sortItems: function (itemOne, itemTwo) {
        return itemOne.sortOrder > itemTwo.sortOrder ? 1 : -1;
    },

    /**
     * @return {Number}
     */
    getActiveItemIndex: function () {
        var activeIndex = 0;

        steps.sort(this.sortItems).forEach(function (element, index) {
            if (element.isVisible()) {
                activeIndex = index;
            }
        });

        return activeIndex;
    },

    /**
     * @param {*} code
     * @return {Boolean}
     */
    isProcessed: function (code) {
        var activeItemIndex = this.getActiveItemIndex(),
            sortedItems = steps.sort(this.sortItems),
            requestedItemIndex = -1;

        sortedItems.forEach(function (element, index) {
            if (element.code == code) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                requestedItemIndex = index;
            }
        });

        return activeItemIndex > requestedItemIndex;
    },

    /**
     * @param {*} code
     * @param {*} scrollToElementId
     */
    navigateTo: function (code, scrollToElementId) {
        var sortedItems = steps.sort(this.sortItems),
            bodyElem = $.browser.safari || $.browser.chrome ? $('body') : $('html');

        scrollToElementId = scrollToElementId || null;

        if (!this.isProcessed(code)) {
            return;
        }
        sortedItems.forEach(function (element) {
            if (element.code == code) { //eslint-disable-line eqeqeq
                element.isVisible(true);
                bodyElem.animate({
                    scrollTop: $('#' + code).offset().top
                }, 0, function () {
                    window.location = window.checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl + '#' + code;
                });

                if (scrollToElementId && $('#' + scrollToElementId).length) {
                    bodyElem.animate({
                        scrollTop: $('#' + scrollToElementId).offset().top
                    }, 0);
                }
            } else {
                element.isVisible(false);
            }

        });
    },

    /**
     * Next step.
     */
    next: function () {
        var activeIndex = 0,
            code;

        steps.sort(this.sortItems).forEach(function (element, index) {
            if (element.isVisible()) {
                element.isVisible(false);
                activeIndex = index;
            }
        });

        if (steps().length > activeIndex + 1) {
            code = steps()[activeIndex + 1].code;
            steps()[activeIndex + 1].isVisible(true);
            window.location = window.checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl + '#' + code;
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    },

    back: function () {
        var activeIndex = 0,
            code;

        steps.sort(this.sortItems).forEach(function (element, index) {
            if (element.isVisible()) {
                element.isVisible(false);
                activeIndex = index;
            }
        });

        if (steps().length > activeIndex - 1) {
            code = steps()[activeIndex - 1].code;
            steps()[activeIndex - 1].isVisible(true);
            window.location = window.checkoutConfig.checkoutUrl + '#' + code;
            document.body.scrollTop = document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
        }
    }
};
});
```

3. Added the overwrite to

> requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
'map': {
    '*': {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator': 'BB_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator-overwrite'
    }
}
 };
```

1. created `back-button.js`

   ```
    define([
   'uiComponent',
   'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
      ], function (Component, stepNavigator) {
   'use strict';

   return Component.extend({
       defaults: {
           template: 'BB_Checkout/back-button'
       },

       /**
        * Back step.
        */
       back: function () {
           stepNavigator.back();
       }
   });
   });
   ```

Comment: It's a shame, that if we want to add a back button to each payment-method, we need to override each payment method's html-template.

Comment: @DaanvandenBergh That's why i added it to 'afterMethods' this way it shows it below the payment methods ;)

Answer (score 3):

The complete working code for Magento version 2.2.2 is:

> checkout_index_index.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
       <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
         <body>
           <referenceBlock name="base-footer-container" remove="false" />
           <move element="secure-shop-logo" destination="micro-header-container" />
            <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
              <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">

                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="back-button" xsi:type="array">

                                                                 <item name="component"  xsi:type="string">Magento_Checkout/js/view/back-button</item>

                                                                   <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">afterMethods</item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>

                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </referenceContainer>
</body>
</page>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/template/back-button.html

```
<div class="actions-toolbar" id="shipping-method-buttons-container">
<div class="primary">
   <div class="back">
      <a data-bind="click: goToPrevStep"
   aria-describedby="checkout-back"
   class="action back">
       <span data-bind="i18n: '&lt; Back'"></span>
     </a>
  </div>
 </div></div>
```

> app/design/frontend/Vendor/yourTheme/Magento_Checkout/web/js/view/back-button.js

```
 define(
[
    'ko',
    'uiComponent',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
],
function (ko, Component, stepNavigator) {
    "use strict";

return Component.extend({

    defaults: {
        template: 'Magento_Checkout/back-button'
    },

    goToPrevStep: function () {
        stepNavigator.navigateTo('shipping');
    }
})
});
```

This is the working code for adding a back button to checkout payment step to go back to shipping step.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easier way to do this, overriding in your theme just the templates file for the payment;
for example, override `vendor/magento/module-purchase-order/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html` in your theme and add where you want the button to appear:

```
<div data-bind="scope: 'checkout.progressBar'">
                <!-- ko foreach: { data: steps().sort(sortItems), as: 'item' } -->
                    <!-- ko if: item.code === 'shipping' -->
                        <div class="secondary">
                            <button class="primary action" data-bind="click: $parent.navigateTo">
                                <span translate="'Go Back'" />
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </div>
```